# jQuery Name Spacing and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces

I'm trying to build a jQuery Plugin using there Name spacing as per there direction here:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing

Now i have run into a problem my plugin need to use a setTimeout to fire one of its methods,

```
var jScrollerMethods = {
    ready:function(){
        return this.each(function(){
        var self = this,
    $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data('jScroller');

        settings.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function(){
            if(settings.direction = "left"){
                this.moveLeft();
            }else if(settings.direction = "right"){
                this.moveRight();
            }
        }, settings.time);

        $this.data('jScroller', {
            settings: settings,
            element: this
        });
    });
}
$.fn.jScroller = function(call){
    if ( jScrollerMethods[call] ) {
      return jScrollerMethods[call].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof call === 'object' || ! call ) {
        if (call) { $.extend(settings, call); }
        return jScrollerMethods.init.apply( this, call );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  call + ' does not exist on jQuery.jScroller' );
    } 
}
```

but as I though would happen setTimeout is fired from the Window not the plugin object and being that I want the plugin to be usable on more than once per page so I can't just save the current object to the window how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you have problems with `this.moveLeft();`? Use `self` (or `$this`) then.

Comment: Thanks but i figured it out now

Comment: Then please provide your solution as answer if you think it will be of use to anyone else, or delete your question.

Comment: i was posting the answer as you commented :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when using `this` outside of the `return this.each` will give you the exact selector results

So with some work i have managed to do it,

```
var jScrollerMethods = {
    ready:function(){
        selector = this;

        return this.each(function(){
        var self = this,
    $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data('jScroller');

        settings.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function(){
            if(settings.direction = "left"){
                selector.jScroller("moveLeft");
            }else if(settings.direction = "right"){
                selector.jScroller("moveRight");
            }
        }, settings.time);

        $this.data('jScroller', {
            settings: settings,
            element: this
        });
    });
}
$.fn.jScroller = function(call){
    if ( jScrollerMethods[call] ) {
      return jScrollerMethods[call].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof call === 'object' || ! call ) {
        if (call) { $.extend(settings, call); }
        return jScrollerMethods.init.apply( this, call );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  call + ' does not exist on jQuery.jScroller' );
    } 
}
```